# App Bar height calculations with MediaQuery fail

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building an app where I wanted to show 4 containers covering the whole available space of on the phone.

For that I am getting the full `width` and `height` of the screen using `MediaQuery.of`. I make the 4 containers fill the entire screen by giving each of them a height of 0.25 of the total height.

The initial code comes here and works fine:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(body: MyHomePage(title: 'Title')),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildMobileLayout(context);
  }

  Widget _buildMobileLayout(BuildContext context) {
    AppBar appBar = AppBar(
      title: Text("My App Title"),
    );

//    var newHeight =
//        (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - appBar.preferredSize.height) *
//            0.25;

    var newHeight = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) * 0.25;

    return Scaffold(
      //appBar: appBar,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: newHeight,
            child: Center(child: Text("Cont 1")),
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: newHeight,
            child: Center(child: Text("Cont 2")),
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: newHeight,
            child: Center(child: Text("Cont 3")),
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: newHeight,
            child: Center(child: Text("Cont 4")),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see on the code above, I am not including the appBar yet, since here is when the problem comes. All works ok without the appBar, but when I include the appBar, even though I am taking care of its height, getting a new total height and splitting it among the 4 containers, I get an error by pixel overflow on the last container.

Phone: Huawei P20 Pro.

Comment: use safearea widget

Comment: not needed, Scaffold appBar should be able to handle this

Comment: @codeKiller What is the exact overflow you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `MediaQuery` you can wrap each of your widgets in a `Expanded` and give them the same `flex`.

```
 return Scaffold(
      //appBar: appBar,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
           Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Center(child: Text("Cont 1")),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Center(child: Text("Cont 2")),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Center(child: Text("Cont 3")),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Center(child: Text("Cont 4")),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i already knew, but still it would be nice to know why my problem is happening, all height calculations look ok for me, and it actually works without appBar